# Как отправлять гиф сообщение в чат с помощью юзер бота pyrogram?

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

Делаю своего юзер бота на python, pyrogram. Хочу сдлать мемную комманду с гифкой таноса
Есть данный код: `app.send_animation("me", "thanos.gif", unsave=True)`, но он отправляет эту гифку мне в **'Избранное'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо `me` подставь id чата

```
app.send_animation("1234567", "thanos.gif", unsave=True)
```

[Документация](https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/methods/send_animation), первый параметр (chat_id)

Comment: Блин, ещё просматривал документацию но про **chat_id** не заметил... Огромное вам спасибо!